# Best module for shared memory in node js?

Tags: node.js

I want to share memory between two individual processes.Can anyone suggest me what will be the best module used in node js.I want to save data in an large array in json format and shared between two process.I am using shm-typed-array module but due to less resources i couldn't solve the issue.

Here is code:

Parent.js:-------------------

```
"use strict";

const shm = require('shm-typed-array');
const fork = require('child_process').fork;

// Create shared memory
const SIZE = 20000000;
const data = shm.create(SIZE, 'Float64Array');

// Fill with dummy data
Array.prototype.fill.call(data, 1);

// Spawn child, set up communication, and give shared memory
const child = fork("child.js");
child.on('message', sum => {
    console.log(`Got answer: ${sum}`);

    // Demo only; ideally you'd re-use the same child
    child.kill();
});
child.send(data.key);
```

Child.js:---------------

```
"use strict";

const shm = require('shm-typed-array');

process.on('message', key => {
    // Get access to shared memory
    const data = shm.get(key, 'Float64Array');

    // Perform processing
    const sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(data, (a, b) => a + b, 0);

    // Return processed data
    process.send(sum);
});
```

Please any suggestion....

Comment: What does _"...but due to less resources i couldn't solve the issue"_ mean?

Comment: can you please suggest me which module will work for shared memory in node js. Any link? Less resources means i didn't find anything to store data using share modules on Google..I am very new to node js

Comment: I can't really recommend one, but take a look here: https://npms.io/search?q=shared+memory

Comment: Which will be best Sir..I am trying to make Uber like app with node js as server.I am trying to save array object {id,value} in json file.So whenever I get a request I can easily search the VALUE by the help of userID and also sending request to Parent.js to Child.js.Any code or source for that.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to use a proper database, or something like [Redis](https://redis.io/).

Comment: How to use Sir...can you please help with the sample of code.I went through Github but it is really hard for me to understand

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend going with Redis currently. This is just a little thrown together example of incrementing a counter every second with redis. You can use .get across processes. If you're looking for a windows version of redis, you can get it here https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads

```
const redis = require('redis');
const client = redis.createClient();

setInterval(() => {
    client.get("count", (error, data) => {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        data++;
        client.set("count", data);
    });
}, 1000);
```